# Which BLE service is used in iOS Temperature example app

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I am studying the iOS temperature app example and it is not mentioned there, which of BLE services is used there?

List of service: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/GATT-Specification-Documents.aspx

I suspected it is "Health Thermometer Service" but there is no maxTemperatureCharacteristic in the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a custom service (not pre-defined in the standard), with a specific 128-bits UUID defined in LeTemperatureAlarmService.h